# Android swipe left and right in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, swipe, ontouchlistener, android-relativelayout

I am trying to implement swipe left or right in my RelativeLayout. I wrote some code but could not get swipe left or right working. I am using GestureDetector
this is a my source

```
private GestureDetector gesturedetector = null;
private RelativeLayout swipelayout;

@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strada_menu_result_loadmore,
            container, false);


    swipelayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);

    gesturedetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener());
    swipelayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;

        }

        });




    return rootView;

}


public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){



    return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}



class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 150;

    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 100;

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        float dX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();

        float dY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();

        if (Math.abs(dY) >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
                && Math.abs(velocityX) >= SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY &&

                Math.abs(dX) >= SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) {

            if (dX > 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Right Swipe",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Left Swipe",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: I suggest you use ViewPager for swiping.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I assume he just wants to detect swipes and not page through `Fragments`. Why else would he use a `GestureDetector`?

Comment: yes i simple want to detect swipe only fragment

Comment: Help us out a little here then. What are you trying to do? What exactly does your code do that you don't want?

Answer (score 8):

You just need an OnTouchListener, that should be all for simple answer. Take a look.
I used this code in some working project, so everything should work fine. But let me know if there is something missing and doesn't work.

```
yourRelativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    int downX, upX;

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             downX = (int) event.getX(); 
             Log.i("event.getX()", " downX " + downX);
             return true;
         } 

         else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             upX = (int) event.getX(); 
             Log.i("event.getX()", " upX " + upX);
             if (upX - downX > 100) {

                 // swipe right
             } 

             else if (downX - upX > -100) {

                 // swipe left
             }
             return true;

             }
             return false;
         }
     });
```

Comment: it not only works for left, but also for 'up' how to restrict 'up'?

Comment: This code up there doesn't take care of Y coordinate. What it basically does is, gets the X coordinate when you first touch on the screen (downX), and gets the X coordinate again when you release your finger (upX). Then it compares these two values to understand which direction your finger moves to. To block "UP" (Meaning +Y Direction), you will need to add downY and upY values, just like X up there. then you can compare these two values, and return false, if you don't that action to be considered.

Comment: And you can also, change the threshold value, from 100 to something bigger. Then you can ignore small X direction changes, when you move your finger in down-up direction.

Comment: it should be:
  if (upX - downX > 100* Constants.density) {
} else if (downX - upX > 100 * Constants.density) {
}

U we're changing the order of the upX - downX and also adding the - to 100 which is incorrect. Right? I mean I took out the - from 100 and it works fine now, doesn't take the Y coordinate, doesn't swipe left at everything I do

Comment: What the code above does is, finds the difference in X coordinates. Between the one when you touch to screen and the one when you release it, `down` and `up`. 100 is the minimum change in the X coordinate. It won't detect the gesture if the difference is less than 100 in X.

Answer (score 1):

Try this will help you....

*OnSwipeTouchListener.java*:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
});
```

Comment: The same answer you gave is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures. You could have suggested the solution through the link or improve it making a better explanation.

Comment: i have syntacs error in setOnTouchListener method can you  changed your code sir ?

Comment: @yashwanth how i can write setOnTouchListener method at the moment ?

Comment: this is   wrong  answer sir. i can not swipe my layout

Comment: l'll edited answer...now try this answer you guys I'm sure it is working right now...